# Select Table Column Heading as Value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table as follows:

> ItemNumber -- Description -- 31.03.2015 -- 31.04.2015 -- 31.05.2015 --
>   31.06.2015
>
> ========= -- ======== -- ======== -- ======== -- ======== -- =========
>
> 001
>   ..................xyz..................null................1000...............null................null
>
> 002
>   ..................xya..................2000................null...............3000................null
>
> 003
>   ..................xyb..................null................4000...............null................5000
>
> 004
>   ..................xyc..................6000................7000...............null................null
>
> 005
>   ..................xyd..................null................8000...............9000................null
>
> 006
>   ..................xye..................null................10000...............null................null
>
> ===================================================================

How can I write a query to return the values such that I can get the column heading of the fields that have a value (are not null) and also get that column heading such as:

> ItemNumber -- Description -- Quantity -- Date
>
> ========= -- ======== -- ====== -- ====
>
> 001.............. -- xyz........... -- 1000...... -- 04/31/2015 12:00:00 AM
>
> 002.............. -- xya........... -- 2000...... -- 03/31/2015 12:00:00 AM
>
> 002.............. -- xya........... -- 3000...... -- 05/31/2015 12:00:00 AM
>
> 003.............. -- xyb........... -- 4000...... -- 04/31/2015 12:00:00 AM

An so on...

Sorry for the terrible formatting, I cannot figure out how to create the proper spacing without the dots.

Comment: Which is you DBMS? (Oracle, MySQL, etc.)

Comment: @BogdanBogdanov MySQL

Comment: What did you try so far? What's the error/non-required behavior?

Comment: @JOrgus Spacing should be preserved if you use the code block.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a massive `union all`:

```
select t.*
from (select ItemNumber, Description, '31.03.2015' as date, `31.03.2015` as quantity
      from table
union all
      select ItemNumber, Description, '31.04.2015' as date, `31.04.2015` as quantity
      from table
      . . .
     ) t
where quantity is not null;
```

In Oracle, you would use double quotes rather than backticks to escape the column name.

And, if you have a lot of data, there are other ways to express the query, so you only scan the table once.

Comment: This is giving me an invalid column name 'quantity', and if I try it without the quotes it doesn't return the quantities, just 31.03.215 all the way down

Comment: @JOrgus . . . I don't see how that could be.  `quantity` is clearly defined in the subqueries.  Be sure you have the quotes correct -- single quotes for `date` and backticks for `quantity`.